# Using ASP.NET identity in a new app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need code review for using ASP.NET Identity in a new app.

Goals:

- Use `int` instead of GUID for IDs.
- Separate identity from view layer

I need code review if I did everything right. Yes it is working but maybe I did something that I shouldn't or maybe there is some place for improvement.

**`ApplicationUser`**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole,
    CustomUserClaim>
    {
        public ICollection<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Store> Stores { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(
    UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> manager)
        {
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(
                this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);            
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class CustomUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> { }
    public class CustomUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int> { }
    public class CustomUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int> { }

    public class CustomRole : IdentityRole<int, CustomUserRole>
    {
        public CustomRole() { }
        public CustomRole(string name) { Name = name; }
    }

    public class CustomUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, int,
        CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
    {
        public CustomUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
        }
    }

    public class CustomRoleStore : RoleStore<CustomRole, int, CustomUserRole>
    {
        public CustomRoleStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
        }
    }
```

**`DbContext`**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, CustomRole,
    int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
    {
        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {...
```

View models are still in view layer. All above is in data layer (class library).
In the view assembly in `AccountController` I changed all `ApplicationUser` to reference `ApplicationUser` in data layer assembly.

I also added extension to get `UserID` as `int`:

```
public static int GetUserIdInt(this IIdentity identity)
        {
            if (identity == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("identity");

            string stringUserId = identity.GetUserId();

            int userId;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringUserId) || !int.TryParse(stringUserId, out userId))
            {
                return default(int);
            }

            return userId;
        }
```

Comment: I'm curious about the `IdentityUser` class, it would be nice if you could include it for context ;)

Comment: `IdentityUser` is class from `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework`.

Comment: Haha can you tell I don't do much web dev! thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: I don't understand? Did I offend you?

Comment: Not at all! Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your customization looks fine - that's the way it is recommended to do it.

The only note I could add is about your **GetUserIdInt** method which you can get rid of. You can just use this generic overload:

```
User.Identity.GetUserId<int>()
```